# Why importing * from a file execute the code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Why exporting nothing from a file (or module), renamed it and just put the variable in the scope **execute** the code?

```
// log.js
console.log('A message');
```

```
// index.js
import * as app from 'log.js';

app;
```

Result: `A message` gets printed, as expected. But if you comment out the `app` line:

```
// log.js
console.log('A message');
```

```
// index.js
import * as app from 'log.js';

// app;
```

Nothing gets printed. What's going on here?

There is an example using codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-keldysh-j0sli

**Update:** I did't realize it was the typescript example I added to the question, I was doing test using typescript and javascript: here's the codesandbox for the js version: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-oskar-0mo2o

Comment: It does execute. His question is why does it when nothing is exported inside log.js

Comment: That's how importing works. It executes the script, and then makes the exported names available in the caller.

Comment: ```export default () => console.log('A message');```

Comment: In fact, people sometimes rely on this behaviour to write [IIFE's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) at the top-level of the imported file

Comment: @Barmar The strange thing is that *just commenting* out the namespace after it's been imported results in the import apparently not being imported at all, despite the `import` still being there. It's an unintuitive Typescript thing.

Comment: Silly me, the link is updated but the code is the exact same thing.

Answer (score 7):

This is expected Typescript behavior. See [Why are imports being elided in my emit?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-imports-being-elided-in-my-emit) and [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9191) on Typescript's github.

> TypeScript assumes that module imports do not have side effects, so it removes module imports that aren't used in any expression.

Without the `app` namespace being used, Typescript doesn't even bother trying to import and run `log.js` because the namespace isn't being used anywhere *and* it assumes the module has no side effects, so there's no point importing it.

If you *do* want to assert that importing alone should have side effects, use:

```
import 'log.ts';
```

This results in the top-level code of `log.ts` being logged as expected.

Note that this is a Typescript-specific behavior. *outside of Typescript*, top-level code of a module *does* run whenever the module is imported, regardless of what was imported or referenced later.

Comment: I think this answer is really accurate but I'm still questioning the Javascript behavior.

Comment: @SergioFlores I think it's a combination of codesandbox weirdness and the build process of react-scripts. Even when things *are* exported from `log` and used in `index`, for some reason, stuff `console.log`ged in `log.js` doesn't get logged, and even `window.alert`s inside `log` don't pop up, unless you happen to be inside the `log.js` tab at the time the script runs. It's doing something very strange - they *aren't* being used as normal ES6 modules. If you run it locally, it won't even compile when `app` isn't used due to eslint, see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2157

Comment: If you use normal ES6 modules instead (or even plain Webpack), rather than whatever complicated stuff React / codesandbox goes through when creating a build, it behaves as you'd expect - stuff in `log` gets logged even when nothing that's imported is used.

Comment: As far i understand, code imported by Dynamic Import `import(<<path>>)` is not run, so `top-level code of a module does run whenever the module is imported` is wrong .